# What really happened in the bridge sequence in the final episode of Golden Time?

Tags: golden-time

Mysticism apart, there are several elements in that sequence that may be real and others that are purely imaginary.

The conversation between ghost Banri and Reawakened Banri is imaginary, but the other elements are confusing...

1. How the ring ends in Banri's pocket? It fell off the bridge. The ghost is soaking wet, implying that he did went into the river to get it, but the ghost cannot interact with the real world unless he is possessing Banri. Banri is dry when he hugs Koko.
2. Linda's response: is it the real Linda that is delivering it (she could have ran after and caught up with Banri while he was discussing with the ghost) or just another figment?
3. How long is that bridge? Is it a real landmark?

Comment: I'm quite confident it was completely real mysticism and that shouldn't be ruled out when you're talking about a ghost. Physical limitations of Ghost Banri may not matter as he was also able to give Banri bad luck for things outside his control.

Comment: Bad luck that could be ruled as completely coincidental. Aside this speculation about the curse ghost Banry placed on Banry for not being able to perceive him, the most mysticism you get in the show prior to finale is the wacko kidnapper cult. So by the end of the series its too late to have something supernatural going on, amidst this whole psychological development. Hence, everything happening inside his mind is the most plausible explanation. @user6338